# Can deploy Smart contract from Main thread but not from a class

Tags: web3j, java

I have a contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract qualification {

address owner;

/* This function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract */
function qualification() { owner = msg.sender; }

/* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); }

}


contract credentials is qualification {

    string studentName;
    string studentEmail;
    string studentUniversity;
    string studentCourse;
    string studentStart;
    string studentEnd;
    string studentClassification;


/* This runs when the contract is executed */
function credentials(string _name, string _email, string _university, string _course, string _start, string _end, string _classification) public {
    studentName = _name;
    studentEmail = _email;
    studentUniversity = _university;
    studentCourse = _course;
    studentStart = _start;
    studentEnd = _end;
    studentClassification = _classification;
}

/* Main function */
function returnQualification() constant returns (string, string, string, string, string, string, string) {
    return (studentName, studentEmail, studentUniversity, studentCourse, studentStart, studentEnd, studentClassification);
}
}
```

That I want to deploy from my Java class,

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService());

                    try {
                        com.example.QualificationAuthenticator.Credentials contract = com.example.QualificationAuthenticator.Credentials.deploy(web3j, creds, Contract.GAS_PRICE, Contract.GAS_LIMIT, record.getStudentName(), record.getStudentEmail(), "uuj", record.getCourseName(), "date", "date2   ", record.getClassification()).send();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("thread couldnt finish");
            }
```

This wont work and I get the error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:302)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$deployRemoteCall$5(Contract.java:334)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:30)

..and more lines of error

However if I put the deploy call inside of my Main thread then the contract deploys fine.

Comment: Apologies..I was passing a null value for credentials. Duh